# having trouble replacing default zeros in 2d array with white spaces

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printf, whitespace

My goal to to make three different 2D arrays, and for the last two replace all zeroes in the array values for blank spaces instead.  I've tried using printf("%s","[]") but instead of replacing the zeros they just add the brackets above the array. i believe it has something to do with the placement of my else statement.

```
public class arrayprgm1{
    public static int[][] Table(int x, int y){//creating first 2D array 
        int[][] array = new int[x][y];
        for (int row= 0; row < array.length; row++){// using for loop to create array
            for (int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop
                    array[row][column]=(row+column)*3;// algorithm used for first 2D array
                }
            }
        int sum = 0;//declaring integer to sum up all of the values created by array 
        for (int row=0; row < array.length; row++){
            for (int column=0; column < array[row].length; column++){
                sum = sum + array[row][column];// algorithm used to sum up values of first array
    } 
    }
    System.out.printf("The total of all the numbers added together is: %2d\n", sum);// using format print to display sum
            return array;//return array created to the main method
        }//end of Table method

    public static int[][] Odds(int x, int y){//creating second 2D array
        int[][]array = new int[x][y];
        for (int row= 0; row < array.length; row++){// using for loop to create array
            for (int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop
                {
                if ((row + column)%2 !=0){ // if statement used to determine if value is odd or even
                    array[row][column]=(row+column)*3;// algorithm used for second array                
                }
                else
                    System.out.printf("%s","[]");
            }
            }
        }
        int sum = 0;//declaring integer to sum up all of the values created by array
        for (int row=0; row < array.length; row++){
            for (int column=0; column < array[row].length; column++){
                sum = sum + array[row][column];// algorithm used to sum up all odd values
    }
    }
    for(int row=0; row< array.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++){

        }
    }System.out.printf("The total of all the odd numbers added together is: %2d\n", sum);//format print used to display sum of all odd numbers
        return array;
    }//end of Odds Method

    public static int[][] Evens(int x, int y){ //Creating the third 2D array that will hold all even values
        int[][] array = new int[x][y];
        for (int row= 0; row < array.length; row++){//for loop to create array
            for (int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop
                {
                if ((row + column)%2 ==0){//if statement used to determine if value is odd or even
                    array[row][column]=(row+column)*3;//algorithm used for third array
                }
                else
                    System.out.printf("%s","[]");
            }
        }
        }       
        int sum = 0;// declaring integer to sum up all the even values
        for (int row=0; row < array.length; row++){//for loop to create array
            for (int column=0; column < array[row].length; column++){//nested for loop
                sum = sum + array[row][column];// algorithm used to sum up all even numbers
    }
    }
    System.out.printf("The total of all the even numbers added together is: %2d\n", sum);// format print used to display sum of all even numbers
        return array;
    }//end of Evens method


    public static void main(String[] args){//main method
        int[][]array  = new int[15][15];//create array to pass to arrays method
        array = Table(15,15);
        for(int row=0; row < array.length; row++){ //for loop to properly display array in a square
            for(int column=0; column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop
                System.out.printf("%4d",array[row][column]);//format the print
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");

        array = Odds(15,15);

        for(int row=0; row < array.length; row++){//for loop to properly display array in square
            for(int column=0; column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop      
                System.out.printf("%4d",array[row][column]);//format the print  
                }   
    System.out.printf("\n");
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");

        array = Evens(15,15);
        for(int row=0; row < array.length; row++){//for loop to properly display array in square
            for(int column=0; column<array[row].length;column++){//nested for loop
                System.out.printf("%4d",array[row][column]);//format the print
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}//end of main method
}//end of public class arrayprgm1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace a zero with a character like space in an array containing integers as you intend to do it. Instead what you need to do this is handle this when you output the array and check for zero values there.

For instance

```
for(int row=0; row < array.length; row++){ 
   for(int column=0; column<array[row].length;column++){
       int value = array[row][column];
       if (value == 0) {
           System.out.printf(" ");
       else {
           System.out.printf("%4d",value);
       }
   }
}
```